# How to change the value of a var from a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, select, var

I have a form in which users may choose which data they want to see.

```
<form>
<div class="myvalues">
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="data1">value 1</option>
<option value="data2">value 2</option>
<option value="data3">value 3</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

In my Javascript section (in the head section of a html page) I have the next variable,

```
var dataFile = 'data1';
```

This is now a static value ('data1')
But I want to replace the 'data1' value with the selected value which was choosen in my form above
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Got jQuery? It's trivial if you do.

Comment: @isherwood Why do you make it sound like it isn't trivial without jQuery?

Comment: It's quite a bit simpler in terms of syntax, but you already know that. Why did you waste time writing a snarky comment rather than providing said trivial answer?

Comment: Because I wonder why people can't/won't do such trivial things without jQuery. jQuery is nice, but you don't need it to do `1+1`. Instead of "wasting time" waiting for a response, why didn't you show him a VanillaJS solution?

Comment: Because I'm not proficient in JS event listener syntax (don't like onclick attributes), but I'd have been able to help with jQuery in short order from memory. We do what we can, right?

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure it is appreciated. I was just wondering why the first comment on something this simple is "jQuery", since there was no reason (for the OP) to use jQuery here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you well, in JavaScript you can ask for the value of the element.

```
var element = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var dataFile = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

If the second option was selected, this should make dataFile having the value "data2"
If you want the text value, you could use this.

```
var element = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var dataFile = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
```

If the second option was selected, this should make dataFile having the value "value 1"

Does this help you?

Comment: The var dataFile gets the value "data2" (I chekced with an alertbox) but this value is not used in the other script that I have. 
For example: var dataFile = 'data2' loads a page with a map and a track drawed on that map. If I have the line <<< var dataFile = 'data2' >>> in my script everything works fine, but when I use your example nothing happens and the page stays blank. 
I assume the value data2 is not used

Comment: This is a bit hard answering, since the other code is missing. I guess if you need more help, the best is to ask another question with all the necessary pieces of code included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document.getElementById() function of javascript to retrieve the current value:

```
dataFile = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gF78U/) for a simple demo.

Answer (score 0):

As Arthur said u can get the option value selected with this code.

```
var dataFile = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

To update the dataFile variable when you change the select value you can create a function on the onchange event of the element.

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById('mySelect');
selectElement.onchange = function(e){
    dataFile = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    console.log(dataFile);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/scZtN/1/)

Comment: See my previous comment, also with your line nothing happens.

Comment: i would need the rest of your code to help you, in this code the dataFile variable always get the current value selected but idk what exactly you want now